# Connection and compactness of Moore's plane.

Tags: general-topology, moore-plane

I'm getting started into this topic in topology (also in Stack Exchange) and wanted to try with a simple example.

I already know that Moore's plane is connected (I saw a proof about it with clausures), but I wanted to prove it by definition. We know it will be connected if $X = A \cup B$ (disjoint).

Therefore, by construction, the Moore plane is as a half-plane  with an "extra edge" on the x-axis. In this "extra edge", each point has a "neighborhood" that extends to the right so every two open sets, no matter what will be connected by this points. However, in case this hypothesis is correct, I don't know how to write it consistently so I wonder if it's possible to explain the connection with balls with its construction.

On the other hand, to prove that it's not compact, here is my try:

Consider the collection of open sets ${U_n}$ where each $U_n$ is the set of all points (x, y) in the Moore plane such that y > n. Basically, each $U_n$ is everything above the y=n line.

This collection ${U_n}$ is an open covering of the Moore plane, because given any point (x, y) in the Moore plane, you can always find a set $U_n$ in the collection such that (x, y) is in $U_n$.

But no finite subcollection of ${U_n}$ can cover the Moore plane. For example, if you take any finite subcollection of ${U_n}$, say ${U_1, U_2, ..., U_N}$, there will always be a point in the Moore plane, like (0, N+1), that is not in any of those sets.

I will greatly appreciate any advice on being more rigorous as I have been penalized a lot before for this reason.

Comment: That $X = A\cup B$ where $A, B$ are disjoint (and open, which you left off) is the definition of $X$ being *disconnected*, not connected. Your description of the Moore plane in the next paragraph is ... incoherent. The first step to improving it is to stop putting quotes around words that you are using with their exact normal meaning and you are not quoting from someone else. The rest of the sentence after "neighborhood" makes no sense. It certainly appears to bear no correspondence to the [actual definition of Moore's plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane).

Comment: In your proof of non-compactness, no point on the edge of the plane lies in any of your sets $U_n$, contradicting yor claim that it is a cover (unless $n$ can be negative, in which case $\{U_{-1}\}$ by itself is a finite subcover in contradiction to your later claim). You assert "you can always find a set $U_n$ in the collection such that $(x,y)$ is in $U_n$" but offer no argument that this is true (it isn't). Then later, you claim $(x,N+1)$ is not in any of $U_1, \dots, U_N$ but by your definition, it is in **all** of them.